# Warning message in WordPress Site. "Argument 1 is not an array" website name ' RealLifeCBD.com '

Tags: php, wordpress

I just merged my WordPress site to In Motion Hosting. And I am getting this message

Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /home/realli31/public_html/wp-content/themes/themify-ultra/theme-functions.php on line 2611

I would like to know how to get rid of this message. I'm new to wordpress so i could really use the help. I've looked all over and I messaged the hosting and plugin sites and have gotten nowhere.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Also I would like to know what does Argument 1 mean?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: first of all you need to learn debugging the code, error message clearly showing that its not an array.